# Рандом из массива без повторения предыдущего значения

Tags: javascript

Собственно проблема описана в заголовке, надо чтобы не повторялось предыдущее значение, буду рад помощи.

```
<div id="amount"></div>

<script>
      function start() {
      var amount = document.getElementById("amount"),
          drillCount = 100,
          drillSpeed = 1000;

      (function iterate(i) {
        amount.innerHTML = i + " Повторений из " + drillCount;
        if (i < drillCount) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            iterate(i + 1);
          var arr = ["left", "right", "center", "up"],
              rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
              console.log(arr[rand]);

          }, drillSpeed);
        }
      })(0);
    }


    start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так может подойти?

```js
function start() {
var amount = document.getElementById("amount"),
    drillCount = 100,
    drillSpeed = 1000,
    lastIndex;

(function iterate(i) {
  amount.innerHTML = i + " Повторений из " + drillCount;
  function random(arr){
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
      if(rand != lastIndex){
        lastIndex = rand;
        return rand;
      }else return random(arr);
  }
  if (i < drillCount) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      iterate(i + 1);
    var arr = ["left", "right", "center", "up"];
        console.log(arr[random(arr)]);

    }, drillSpeed);
  }
})(0);
}


start();
```

```html
<div id="amount"></div>
```

Comment: Увы нет, в Вашем решении переберется весь массив, а дальше выводит undefined. Нужно только избежать повторения с пред. значением.

Comment: @s0nly чтобы всегда было 4 разных значения?

Comment: @s0nly, дополнил ответ